# Positioning of node with two measurements

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following quote is found Chapter 17, section 5.3 in the pgf manual. ("This option" refers to the specification of the location of a node by two measurements.):

> The effect of this option is the following. First, the point `(<number or dimension 2>, <number or dimension 1>)` is computed using the normal rules for evaluating such a coordinate, yielding some position. Then, the node is shifted by the vertical component of this point. The anchor is set to south.

I am providing the example provided in the manual. Does the example illustrate "this option"?  How does `and 3mm` change the position of the node?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2);
\node at (1,1) [above=0.2 and 3mm, draw] {over};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone want to offer a better illustrative example?

Comment: To use `and 3mm` you need to give `above left` or `above right`

Comment: @ Harish Kumar The manual says that "the reason (this option of using two measurements)  is allowed for the `above` option is that it is sometimes automatically used," but it is almost always used for `above left` and similar options.  Strangely, the only example the manual gives is using the `above` option!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option doesn't work unless you add `above right`, `above left` or `below right`, `below left`. Also, you'll have different results if you leave the `and 3mm` out. Compare the following:

- `[above right=0.2, draw]`

  [image]
- `[above right=0.2 and 3mm, draw]`

  [image]

As explained in the quote, the anchor is set to the south of the node. The anchor is what is being "moved". The rest of the shape, of course, follows. If you don't know what anchors are, check the section 49 "Shapes" in the [Tikz-Pgf manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) (page 477). If you wanted you could set a different anchor, by adding the key `anchor=north` or `anchor=north west` in the options.

A circle would work the same way, except that the anchor is set to the center of the circle, not south. If you change your example to have `\node at (1,1) [circle, draw] {over};`, you'll see that it's positioned at the exact center, but if you add `anchor=south`, it will be moved up so that its south matches the center of the grid.

Comment: The two displays you provide are different.  Does the `and 3mm` move the node horizontally?  What does `above right =0.2` do with the node?  My guess is that `TikZ` moves the node diagonally 0.2 centimeters.

Comment: @Adelyn Yes, in the first case, it moves it diagonally. In the second case, it moves it 0.2 up and 3mm right/left. :)

Comment: In the first example, it does look like the lower left corner is moved diagonally 2 millimeters and, in the second example, it does look like the lower left corner is moved one and a half times more rightward than upward.  Thanks.  (The manual did not say that!)

Comment: @Adelyn Yes manuals don't always mention everything, but some things can be understood with some trial and error (and luck). :D

Comment: You said `above right=0.2 and 3mm` moves "it" 2 millimeters up from the coordinate  and 3 millimeters to the right.  What is "it"?  I guess it is the lower left corner of the box. What gets moved if I had ``below left=0.2 and 3mm`?  What happens with a circular node?

Comment: I think your answers to these questions should clarify the situation.  Thanks.

Comment: @Adelyn Sorry I was asleep when you wrote that. I added some info to the answer in response to your other questions.

Comment: Thanks for editing your original reply.  I interpret this to mean that the option `[anchor shape=south,circle,draw]` will draw a circle about the text and position it in the same place as the option `[above, circle, draw]`.  Is that correct?

Comment: No, it should be `[circle, draw, anchor=south]` without "shape". :) Yes, it will be in the same position.

Comment: I looked at the example of placing nodes about a circle on page 477 of the manual of which you provided the link.  I am not familiar with the `foreach` declaration; so, I do not know how to apply this code to simpler examples.  It seems to me that "s.10" and "s.130" are placed at an angle of 10 degrees and an angle of 130 degrees, respectively.  How would I place these labels using the code that you provided?  (How is the "s." typeset in the example in the manual?)

Comment: @Adelyn I think you should ask a new question for that. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a need for some more clarification. First of all why there is no syntax error. That's because it saves a lot of if then syntax. Check out the internal code for these options in the archaic style of `\tikzoption` (which is equivalent to `\tikzset`)

```
\tikzoption{above}[]{\def\tikz@anchor{south}\tikz@possibly@transform{y}{}{#1}}
\tikzoption{below}[]{\def\tikz@anchor{north}\tikz@possibly@transform{y}{-}{#1}}
\tikzoption{above left}[]%
  {\def\tikz@anchor{south east}%
    \tikz@possibly@transform{x}{-}{#1}\tikz@possibly@transform{y}{}{#1}}
```

Now, you don't need to know what it does with possibly transforming etc. But you notice that if you give above, below etc. It discards the x information even if you provide explicitly 0.2 and 3mm.

Also you can see the opposite anchoring in effect: you choose one option and it chooses the opposite compass direction for anchoring. If you want to override it, you have to add explicit `anchor=<foo>` to your options.

By enabling a finer grid you can actually see the positioning better

```
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1mm] (2,2) node at (1,1) {o};
\node at (1,1) [circle,above=0.2 and 3mm, draw] {over};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

And also with above right you get the exact amount of shift

```
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1mm] (2,2) node at (1,1) {o};
\node at (1,1) [ellipse,above right=0.2 and 3mm, draw] {over};
\fill[red] (1,1) ++(3mm,2mm) circle(0.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Based on your reply, I understand that with the specification "0.2 and 3mm," `TikZ` ignores "3mm" if either `above` or `below` is specified, and `TikZ` ignores "0.2" if either "right" or "left" is specified.

Comment: Your second example seems to illustrate that using `above right` is the same as using `anchor=south east` and that the point on the ellipse that is the anchor is one of the two intersections of the line of slope 1 through the center of the ellipse with the ellipse.

Comment: @Adelyn Yes the intersection of a ray from center and the shapeborder at 225 degrees (it can be a more complicated shape).